# File renaming functions in wordpress upload process

Tags: wordpress

I have a script that loads posts automatically from a predefined array and uploads images as featured images from a physical path on a local machine.

When I copy the file into upload directory I use path and filename like so:

```
$upload_dir['path'].'/'.$new_post_id.$filename
```

This way if I upload apple.jpg several times, the file will be named 1apple.jpg, 2apple.jpg and so on and it will not be overwritten.

I would however like to use Wordpress native functions that check and rename files. In wordpress uploads if you upload apple.jpg several times it will add a new number before the extension like so: apple1.jpg, apple2.jpg and so on, and the number portion is not based on a post.

I was wondering if you could point me to the function in wordpress that does this check and creates new filename so I can use the wordpress native functions for naming my uploaded files.

Comment: I actually kinda like your solution. Why not just `split` your `$filename` and append the `$new_post_id` before the file extension?

Comment: @crowjonah I was looking for the function that wordpress uses, and it turns out to be wp_unique_filename()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: wp_unique_filename()

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter the function [`wp_unique_post_slug()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/post.php#L2834).

As discussed in [WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73983/12615).